# Post Image data in android studio to a server url not working on android 4.1.2

Tags: android, http-post

I am taking a screenshot on my android app using this code:

```
       Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                final String ts = tsLong.toString();
               
                String mPath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/ScreenShot/" + ts + ".jpg";
                // create bitmap screen capture
                View v1 = main;
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                int quality = 100;
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
```

I am then sending this screenshot to a server using the following:

```
 String url = "http://website.com/";
            StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("takeScreenshot", "onResponse: "+response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("takeScreenshot", "error: "+error);
                    //This code is executed if there is an error.
                }
            }) {
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    MyData.put("image_tag", ts);
                    MyData.put("image_data", getStringImage(bitmap));
                    return MyData;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SecondActivity.this);
            RetryPolicy mRetryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
            MyStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);
            requestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
```

This code works fine on any android that is 5.0+ but not on the 4.1.2 that I am using, for some reason this code takes the screenshot and tries to send the post request but doesn't and it does not enter the `onResponse` or `onErrorResponse`

I have added this `RetryPolicy mRetryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);`       `MyStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(mRetryPolicy);` to try and fix my problem but it did nothing

Comment: `getStringImage(bitmap))` It is unclear what you send. And what is the error you get? Or which statement is executed last? Or where does it hang? And is it relevant that you posted code that compresses a bimap to file?

Comment: `getStringImage(bitmap))` send the image data `requestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);` is the last line executed. and if I remove the image data from the URL post request it goes through but not with the image data that's why I added the image code

Comment: `getStringImage(bitmap)) send the image` No that will not send anything. And you did not tell and show what this statement does.

Comment: it is essentially in this statement `MyData.put("image_data", getStringImage(bitmap));` sending the image data under the name `image_data` in other word `getStringImage(bitmap)` gathers the image data and the `.put()` places the data inside the post request as additional data. example: here the data is sent like this: `link.././image_tag=name&image_data=dqfqrqeqwfr3232r2t2gf2...`

Comment: You still did not tell what getStringImage does. And what it returns. You did not tell or show how you convert a bitmap to a string. Or put a bitmap in a string.